# How well will ntpd work when the latency is highly variable?

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I have an application where we are using some non-standard networking equipment (cannot be changed) that goes into a dormant state between traffic bursts. The network latency is **very** high for the first packet since it's essentially waking the system, waiting for it to reconnect, and then making the first round-trip. Subsequent messages (provided they are within the next minute or so) are much faster, but still highly-latent. A typical set of pings will look like 2500ms, 900ms, 880ms, 885ms, 900ms, 890ms, etc.

Given that NTP uses several round trips before computing the offset, how well can I expect ntpd to work over this kind of link? Will the initially slow first round trip be ignored based on the much different (and faster) following messages to/from the ntp server?

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is yes, NTP will prefer low round trip timestamps over high round trip timestamps. There used to be a `calldelay` option to tell NTP about this problem, typically created by networks that used dial-on-demand technologies that impose a call delay. However, now NTP does this automatically.

If you want to speed up initial timesync, you may wish to use the `iburst` keyword on the `server`/`peer` lines. This tells NTP to use 8 spaced out packets instead of 1 to measure the time. It will ignore any packets that have much higher round trip times. If you have the bandwidth, you can use `burst` to make it use 8 packets every time it measures the time.